# Update custom field on opportunity with the opportunity line items

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, standard-objects

I am trying to update field List_of_products__c at Opportunity when Opportunity line item is added on the opportunity.

Eg. Opportunity line items details should get populated with ',' in List_of_products__c  long text field.

I have tried this so far.

```
trigger UpdateOppWithProd on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

List<Opportunity> oppUpdate = new List <Opportunity>();
if(Trigger.isInsert)
{
   for(OpportunityLineItem pro:trigger.new)
   {
    oppIds.add(pro.Id);
   }
}

if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete)

{
    for(OpportunityLineItem pro:trigger.new)
    {
    oppIds.add(pro.Id);
    }
}

for(Opportunity opp: [Select id, Name, List_of_Products__c,(Select Id, Name from OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id IN:oppIds])
{
    System.debug('Oppppppp=====>>>'+opp);
    Opportunity oppObj = new Opportunity();
    oppObj.Id = opp.Id;
    oppObj.List_of_Products__c = string.join(opp.OpportunityLineItems,',');
    oppObj.Name = opp.Name;
    oppUpdate.add(oppObj);
    
 }
Update oppUpdate;
}
```

Please let me know what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Use trigger.old in the context of update and delete.
if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete)

{
    for(OpportunityLineItem pro:trigger.old)
    {
    oppIds.add(pro.Id);
    }
}

Comment: You have shown what you tried so far, but not explained at all how the behavior you observe differs from that you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oppIds.add(pro.Id);
```

Should be:

```
oppIds.add(pro.OpportunityId);
```

You're trying to query the Opportunities using OpportunityLineItem Ids, so nothing gets returned from the query.

In addition, in an after delete trigger, `Trigger.new` doesn't exist, you need to use `Trigger.old`.

---

```
trigger UpdateOppWithProd on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Opportunity> oppUpdate = new List <Opportunity>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem pro:Trigger.new==null? Trigger.old: Trigger.new) {
        oppIds.add(pro.OpportunityId);
    }
    for(Opportunity opp: [Select id, Name, List_of_Products__c,(Select Id, Name from OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id IN:oppIds]) {
        Opportunity oppObj = new Opportunity();
        oppObj.Id = opp.Id;
        String[] productNames = new String[0];
        for(OpportunityLineItem item: opp.OpportunityLineItems) {
            productNames.add(item.Name);
        }
        oppObj.List_of_Products__c = String.join(productNames,',');
        oppObj.Name = opp.Name;
        oppUpdate.add(oppObj);
    }
    Update oppUpdate;
}
```